# Ultra compact css

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs

I would like to know if there is any way to compress CSS by merging all equal properties.

Example:

**My css file:**

```
.main{
    border: 3px solid red;
 }

.container .child{
    border: 3px solid red;
    background: blue;
}

element{
   margin: 4px 0px;
}

.xpto > li{
    border: 3px solid red;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    background: red;
}
```

**Need output:**

```
.main, .container .child, .xpto > li{
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.container .child{
    background: blue;
}
.xpto li, element{
    margin: 4px 0px;
}
.xpto li{
    background: red;
}
```

Does anyone know any way?

Comment: Either you write it like the wanted output to begin with, or you use some type of LESS, SASS, CSS compiler with variables

Comment: I doubt that would even make sense - I'd bet that would easily get you in trouble in a lot of places where it comes to equal specificity vs rule ordering.

Comment: I agree with @junkfoodjunkie. You should also consider that you're going to run into a nasty antipattern and probably hate yourself when you have to do some type of maintenance. In all reality, gzipping your project will yield ideal results because gzip looks for repetition. Meaning, your 1st example is actually better than your needed output.

Comment: Yeah,and/or simply minifying the css to remove whitespace, which would also yield performance gains without requiring rewriting, transpiling or otherwise futzing with the underlying meaning/structure of your code.  Upvoted bc an interesting question, but ultimately I think the advice you'll get is less how to do it and more why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with `gulp`, a gulp plugin called `gulp-cssnano` would be able to minify your CSS in the way that you describe in your question.

Read about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssnano).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not 100% what was asked – but it could be done with SCSS @extend

```
%back-blue{ background: blue; }
%back-red { background: red; }
%border   { border: 3px solid red; }
%margin   { margin: 4px 0; }

.main { 
  @extend %border; 
}   
.container .child {
  @extend %border;
  @extend %back-blue;
}
element {
  @extend %margin;
}
.xpto > li {
  @extend %border;
  @extend %margin;
  @extend %back-red;
}
```

Output:

```
.container .child { background: blue; }
.xpto > li { background: red; }
.main, .container .child, .xpto > li { border: 3px solid red; }
element, .xpto > li { margin: 4px 0; }
```

Comment: **Tks Jakob.**

I was thinking something along the same path. It would not be the prettiest solution, but I would like something like that for the production environment.